# ayuda con CSS de un elemento div HTML

Tags: html, css

Tengo una pagina maestra y dentro mas paginas html, en una de ellas añadi un div, pero no logro mover el div rojo mas a la izquierda:
En la imagen se muestra como se ve actualmente pero quiero moverlo mas a la izquierda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="grafica "></div>
```

```html
.grafica {
float:left;
 margin-left:0px; 
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
   font-size: x-small; 
   width:378px; 
   Height:150px; 
   background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Tienes que mandar el codigo HTML de tu pagina para poderla probar porque asi no me dices mucho. Sludos

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el HTML y CSS del resto de la página?  Porque si veo este html en un navegador sólo veo el cuadro rojo a la izquierda, pero no se ve la linea azul ni el espacio que comentás.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Agrega a tu **CSS** **left:0px;**

```
.grafica {
    float:left;
    left:0px;
    margin-left:0px; 
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-small; 
    width:378px; 
    Height:150px; 
    background-color:red;
}
```